# How to prove that if $x\in X$ and $y\notin\overline{ X}$ then $|[x,y]\cap\partial X|=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ let us define $[x,y]=\{(1-t)x+ty\in\mathbb{R}^n;\;t\in[0,1]\}$. Geometrically (in two or three dimensions), $[x,y]$ is the line connecting $x$ and $y$.

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\in X$ and $y\notin\overline{X}$. If we draw a picture in the plane, "we can see" that there exists a unique point $z\in\partial X$ such that $z\in[x,y]\cap\partial X$. How to prove formally that it is generally true?

Comment: There are generally several points in $[x,y] \cap \partial X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you give me an example?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ take $X = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and $x = 0.5, y = 4$.  Then the intersection of the interval and boundary has two elements.

Comment: If you assume $X$ is convex, the intersection is unique.

Comment: @Addem: three,actually.

Comment: @tomasz, right, forgot to correct that when I moved $y$ from 2.5 to 4 to keep $y$ out of the closure.

Comment: Or infinitely many are possible. Pick $x$ and $y$ and draw a Jordan curve with $x$ inside, $y$ outside, and a segment of $[x,y]$ part of the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not generally true. Take in $\Bbb R^2$ the set $$X=[0,1]\times (\Bbb Q\cap [0,1])$$ pick a point inside and one outside. We have that $\partial X=\overline X=[0,1]^2$, so your claim fails (quite dramatically!). If you're thinking about "nice enough" sets, for example, one such that $\partial X$ is a Jordan curve, then the answer is still not true, for example, take a horseshoe figure and a point inside one of the ends of the horseshoe, towards a point outside the other end (i.e. exploit nonconvexity). If $\partial X$ is a convex Jordan curve, the answer should be positive.

Comment: My pictures were all convex Jordan curves. What is the proof for this kind of curve?

Comment: @Pedro I wouldn't think the proof is something trivial. You're essentially proving that any Jordan curve is homotopic to a circle, and I wouldn't think that is simple. To start talking about "inside" and "outside" of a Jordan curve, you need the Jordan Curve Theorem, which is a big one!